# Django: How to check object category when using Model Inheritance?

Tags: python, django

Here is my `models.py` the idea of app is to have different objects (restaurants, services, etc) with different features (you can check each Model). But when I want to get all objecs `Object.objects.all()` I don't know which is the category for each of them.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import ProfileUser
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Object(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    site = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_object = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"


class Restaurant(Object):
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    bulgarian_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    italian_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    french_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_garden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_playground = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class SportFitness(Object):
    is_fitness_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CarService(Object):
    is_parts_clients = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class BeautySalon(Object):
    is_hair_salon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_laser_epilation = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class FastFood(Object):
    is_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_duner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_seats = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CarWash(Object):
    is_external_cleaning = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_internal_cleaning = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_engine_cleaning = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Fun(Object):
    is_working_weekend = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_kids_suitable = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Other(Object):
    is_working_weekend = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Comment(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.content}"
```

Comment: django-polymorphic could be something you might want to take a look at. -> https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get the categories using the Object model.
Object class is created for a particular purpose:
**it eliminates the need to declare certain characteristics of a class**

Here you can use select_related or prefect_related to get the desired output.

OR

To fulfill your requirements you can use **django-polymorphic** for more detail you can [refer](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) the documentation.

Comment: For `select_related` I should add an additional row(column) to Object Class, for category  right ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm No, you can add additional row(column) if you are using django-polymorphic. But not for select_related.
For Example:- Objects.objects.select_related("author") provides you data of all the tables in which "author" is present in a single query.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm if my answer is helpful, please give a upvote

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

Based on @wfehr commend and @Lokesh Pathak answer I implemented [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html), also added two additional rows(columns) to each model (only for Restaurants for now), so when foreach over all object I can print exact name of category, additional fields are

```
category_en_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='restaurants')
category_bg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Ресторант')
```

full `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import ProfileUser
from django.utils import timezone
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

# Create your models here.

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Object(PolymorphicModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    site = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_object = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"


class Restaurant(Object):
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    bulgarian_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    italian_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    french_kitchen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category_en_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='restaurants')
    category_bg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Ресторант')
    is_garden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_playground = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class SportFitness(Object):
    is_fitness_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So I can take only Restaurants in views.py:

```
objects = Object.objects.instance_of(Restaurant)
```

And in template, I can show category name of each restaurant:

```
{% for object in objects %}
{{ object.category_bg_name }}
{% endfor %}
```